# Bluetooth disconnection alarm

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, tone-generator

I want to create bluetooth android app such that when it gets disconnected from the connected device it beeps an audio. I used the following code

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();     
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);    
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);  
this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

But in these cases if any one of the devices(two) is taken away a 1cm it beeps i want it to beep atleast when any of the device crosses the range of bluetooth?????

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
    ToneGenerator toneGen  = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
               //Device found
            }
            else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
               //Device is now connected
               toneGen.stopTone(); // Stop alarm / beep when connected again
            }
            else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                //Done searching
            }
            else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
               //Device is about to disconnect
            }
            else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
               //Device has disconnected

                 toneGen.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_ONE_MIN_BEEP)
            }           
        }
        };
```

Comment: But the thing with bluetooth is it by default gets inactive if it is left idle. Moreover, the idle time I am talking about is 2 to 3 seconds. So, even if the actual connection is not broken the beep will get played?? So, the purpose doesn't gets solved.

Comment: Looks like you want to prevent from bluetooth connection getting lost after being idle after some time. There is this person who claims to have solved the same issue. Ref - http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/id-3177931/bluetooth-device-disconnecting.html
It might help you.
He has removed "keep device visible for..."  option from his device